# Get list of files on external SD

Tags: android

I need a way to get all txt files from the SD cards.

I wrote this code:

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ||  Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            myTxt = findTxt(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
}
```

But it returns me all txt files of the internal memory of the smartphone.

How is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are conflating [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). You do not have filesystem-level access to all of removable storage on Android 4.4+.

If you are willing to find all text files anywhere, query the `MediaStore`, which will index removable storage. Just bear in mind that you will then need to get at the contents of the text files via a `Uri` that you get from the `MediaStore`, using things like `ContentProvider` and `openInputStream()`.

Comment: @xRobot: Whether `MediaStore` indexes removable storage is up to the device manufacturer (or custom ROM developer). However, `MediaStore` did not start indexing all files until Android 3.0 IIRC -- before that, it was just for media.